# How can I add a black box on an image with responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is a Codecademy project, but they don't have a solution and I am trying to do it by myself. So as you can see, if you open this in a large window it appears fine. But there is one thing I am really struggling with.

Those black boxes in the top and bottom image. I used absolute position to translate them there, which probably isn't the best idea, but I didn't know how else to do it.

Any ideas on better ways to do it for a more responsive design?

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  border-bottom: solid 1px white;
  z-index: 10;
}

header ul {
  float: right;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header img {
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.top-image img {
  max-height: 700px;
  margin-top: 69px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}

.text-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 330px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

.teas {
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.col {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {
  max-width: 300px;
}

figcaption {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-locations-background.jpg");
}

.bottom h2 {
  transform: translatey(100px);
}

.blackbox-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(110px, -350px);
}

.blackbox-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(450px, -350px);
}

.blackbox-3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(790px, -350px);
}

.final {
  height: 200px;
}

footer {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Tea Cozy</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" />
    <ul>
      <li>Mission</li>
      <li>Featured Tea</li>
      <li>Locations</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="top-image">
    <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h2>Our Mission</h2>
    <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="teas">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h4>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col">
        <figure>
          <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg" />
          <figcaption>Bedford Bizarre Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg" />
          <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <figure>
          <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg" />
          <figcaption>Seasonal Donuts</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg" />
          <figcaption>Myrtle Ave Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <figure>
          <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg" />
          <figcaption>Spiced Rum Tea</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="bottom-image">
      <h2>Locations</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="blackbox-1">
      <h3>Downtown</h3>
      <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
      <h4>Suite 108</h4>
      <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="blackbox-2">
      <h3>Downtown</h3>
      <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
      <h4>Suite 108</h4>
      <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="blackbox-3">
      <h3>Downtown</h3>
      <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
      <h4>Suite 108</h4>
      <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="final">
    <h2>The Tea Cozy</h2>
    <h5>contact@theteacozy.com</h5>
    <h5>917-546-8464</h5>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h5>copyright The Tea Cozy 2017</h5>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't create a totally responsive setup with px units as you have found. Instead you could investigate putting the boxes in a div and placing that a % up from the bottom and displaying it flex - CSS will then sort out the spacing between them.

Comment: You can't call a layout responsive with fixed widths anyway. Start with your overall layout, then worry about the boxes. Also, you're misusing heading elements. They should not be arbitrarily applied for styling purposes. Look into semantic document structure.

Comment: @isherwood I dont understand whats wrong with my <header> elements? Its the introductory content, as it has the logo, links, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use fixed width when you want to get a responsive website. I recommend to use mostly flexbox and % widths. And only give max-width to container layout elements.

I wrote over your code to make some of the parts responsive, only some modifications and proposals, otherwise you won't learn if I do it for you.

For your blackbox on your image, there's few solutions. The one you did with absolute position. Then you need a parent element and give it the position relative, so the absolute element can adapt to the parent.

Then for the responsive side, I added @media queries that allows you to set font size for each width of devices.

```css
html{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color:seashell;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-align: center;
}
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header{
  height: 69px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

header .header-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 69px;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;
    z-index: 10;
}

header ul{
    float: right;
}

header li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
header img{
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.top-image img{
    max-height: 700px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;

}
.text-center{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.text-center h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.text-center h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.teas{
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.col{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}

figcaption{
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bottom{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-locations-background.jpg");
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4rem 0;
}

.bottom-title {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.wrapper-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .text-center h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  
  .wrapper-content {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
  .wrapper-content {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }
}

.bottom-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-locations-background.jpg");
}

.blackbox{
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
  width: 240px;

}
.blackbox-2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
    transform: translate(450px, -350px);
}
.blackbox-3{
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
    transform: translate(790px, -350px);
}

.final{
    height: 200px;
}

footer{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Tea Cozy</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
              <header>
          <div class="header-wrapper">
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-tea-cozy-logo.png"/>
            <ul>
                <li>Mission</li>
                <li>Featured Tea</li>
                <li>Locations</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <div class="top-image">
            <img src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-mission-background.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center">
              <h2>Our Mission</h2>
              <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, 
                  Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="teas">
            <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
            <h4>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h4>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col">
                    <figure>
                        <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg"/>
                        <figcaption>Bedford Bizarre Tea</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-berryblitz.jpg"/>
                        <figcaption>Fall berry Blitz Tea</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <figure>
                        <img class="image"                                            src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-donut.jpg"/>
                        <figcaption>Seasonal Donuts</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-myrtle-ave.jpg"/>
                        <figcaption>Myrtle Ave Tea</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <figure>
                        <img class="image" src="https://content.codecademy.com/courses/freelance-1/unit-4/img-spiced-rum.jpg"/>
                        <figcaption>Spiced Rum Tea</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="bottom-container">            
                <h2 class="bottom-title">Locations</h2>
          <div class="wrapper-content">           
            <div class="blackbox">
                <h3>Downtown</h3>
                <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
                <h4>Suite 108</h4>
                <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="blackbox">
                <h3>Downtown</h3>
                <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
                <h4>Suite 108</h4>
                <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="blackbox">
                <h3>Downtown</h3>
                <h4>384 West 4th St</h4>
                <h4>Suite 108</h4>
                <h4>Portland, Maine</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="final">
            <h2>The Tea Cozy</h2>
            <h5>contact@theteacozy.com</h5>
            <h5>917-546-8464</h5>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <h5>copyright The Tea Cozy 2017</h5>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you :)